Angular & Bootstrap - Routes
I have created a menu, breadcrumbs, with components and their children. The problem is that I see the first child perfectly with  but when I open a child of that child (grandchildren so to speak) the component opens under its parent. My goal is to remove the parent's view and show only the child's. I leave code for better understanding. The father is casilleros.component and his child is historial.component
<!-- dashboard.component.html -->
<div class="dashboard-container">
    <app-menu></app-menu>
    <div class="content-area">
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
        <app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
        <div class="dashboard-content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

// app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'navbar', component: NavbarComponent },
  {
    path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Dashboard' },
    children: [
      { path: 'permisos', component: PermisosComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Permisos' }},
      { path: 'operarios', component: OperariosComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Operarios' }},
      { path: 'maquinas', component: MaquinasComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Máquinas' }},
      { path: 'materiales', component: MaterialesComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Materiales' }},
      { 
        path: 'casilleros', component: CasillerosComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Casilleros' },
        children: [
          { path: 'historial', component: HistorialComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Historial' }, outlet: 'casilleros' }
        ]
      },
--
--
--


    <!-- casilleros.component.html -->
    <div class="container mt-4">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control w-50" placeholder="Buscar">
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Referencia</th>
                    <th>Ubicación</th>
                    <th>Activo</th>
                    <th>Ocupado</th>
                    <th>Acción</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
                    <td>{{i}}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.referencia }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.ubicacion }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check form-switch">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="activo{{ item.referencia }}" checked>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check form-switch">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ocupado{{ item.referencia }}" checked>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button (click)="goToHistorial(item)" class="btn btn-sm"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm"><i class="bi bi-pencil"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <router-outlet name="casilleros"></router-outlet>
    </div>


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-casilleros',
  templateUrl: './casilleros.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./casilleros.component.css']
})
export class CasillerosComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  items = [
    { referencia: 101, ubicacion: 'Vinilo' },
    { referencia: 102, ubicacion: 'Vinilo' },
    { referencia: 103, ubicacion: 'Vinilo' },
    { referencia: 104, ubicacion: 'Vinilo' },
    { referencia: 105, ubicacion: 'Vinilo' },
    { referencia: 106, ubicacion: 'Vinilo' },
    { referencia: 107, ubicacion: 'Vinilo' },
    { referencia: 108, ubicacion: 'Vinilo' },
    { referencia: 109, ubicacion: 'Vinilo' },
    { referencia: 110, ubicacion: 'Vinilo' }
  ];

  goToHistorial(item: any) {
     this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { casilleros: ['historial'] } }]);
  }
}


If i understand you correctly. Your problem lies in the structure of your routing and how you manage the display of child components within your angular application.
Do the following step.

Remove the named router from casilleros.component.html
Adapt the navigation in your casilleros.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-casilleros',
  templateUrl: './casilleros.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./casilleros.component.css']
})
export class CasillerosComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  goToHistorial(item: any) {
     this.router.navigate(['dashboard/casilleros/historial']);
  }
}

Update
I created a stackblitz to better understand your problem.
When you nest routes, the child component is rendered within the parent's router-outlet, causing both views to display together.
To display HistorialComponent when navigating from CasillerosComponent, restructure your routes so that HistorialComponent replaces the parent view (CasillerosComponent), instead of rendering within it.
Do the following step.

Adapt routes: Move HistorialComponent within the same level of CasillerosComponent

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'navbar', component: NavbarComponent },
  {
    path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Dashboard' },
    children: [
      { path: 'permisos', component: PermisosComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Permisos' }},
      { path: 'operarios', component: OperariosComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Operarios' }},
      { path: 'maquinas', component: MaquinasComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Máquinas' }},
      { path: 'materiales', component: MaterialesComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Materiales' }},
      { path: 'casilleros', component: CasillerosComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Casilleros' },},
      { path: 'historial', component: HistorialComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Historial' },},
    ],
  },
];



Remove the named router from casilleros.component.html
Adapt the navigation in your casilleros.component.ts

    this.router.navigate(['dashboard/historial']);


Thanks for the reply. It's not working :-(
It takes me to dashboard

I saw that you have declared the outlet in the routes as well.. Remove the outlet: 'casilleros' of the following route { path: 'historial', component: HistorialComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'Historial' }, outlet: 'casilleros' }

The url changes but the view doesn't. When I click the button to go the historialComponent the casillerosComponent remains in view.

It is a possible and temporary solution although I would like the breadcrumbs to work correctly since the history will depend on the box selected in the magnifying glass button. But thanks, I'm moving on for now :-)

You can add relativeTo: this.activatedRoute, to perform the secondary outlet navigation based on the current route position. Then the path will be recognizable.
...
constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
...

...
goToHistorial(item: any) {
     this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { casilleros: ['historial'] } }], {
         relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
     });
}


Example demo:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-other-page',
  template: `
    <p>
      other page works!
    </p>
    <button (click)="goToHistorial(item)" class="btn btn-sm">test</button>
    <router-outlet name="widget"></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class OtherPageComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
  goToHistorial(item: any) {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { widget: ['mywidget'] } }], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks, It is working but it doesn't remove the parent's html, it shows the content of the lower child to its parent. My intention is to remove the parent's content from the view and display the child's content
